# Merging CSV lines where column value is the same

Tags: php, csv

I have a big CSV file with about 30 columns and 2.5K rows.

Some of the rows have exactly the same values except some columns.

I would like to merge those alike and concatenate with a comma between the values of the columns that are not the same.

Small example:

```
id  name  age  kid
1   Tom   40   John
1   Tom   40   Roger
---merged becomes---
1   Tom   40   John, Roger
```

I can do this with PHP using lots and lots of fors and ifs but I am hoping that there's a more elegant and fast way.

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Please read the last line in my post.

Comment: I read the last line and it does not demonstrate what you have tried. Have you considered doing this in the query?

Comment: Doing it in the query would be my last option as I got the CSV but no access to the database. There's nothing to try, it's just a foreach line in csv, create object, compare values in fileds, add data to the object's attribute where it's not the same as the previous ones but the main id is the same. (I've made the class that will store the data already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great beginner question for a common programming problem. What you'll want to do is a two step approach. First, parse the CSV into a data structure that you can easily modify, then loop over that structure and generate a new array that matches the output.

```
<?php

// Parse CSV into rows like:
$rows = array(
    array(
        'id'   => 1,
        'name' => 'Tom',
        'age'  => 50,
        'kid'  => 'John'
    ),
    array(
        'id'   => 1,
        'name' => 'Tom',
        'age'  => 50,
        'kid'  => 'Roger'
    ),
    array(
        'id'   => 2,
        'name' => 'Pete',
        'age'  => 40,
        'kid'  => 'Pete Jr.'
    ),
);

// Array for output
$concatenated = array();

// Key to organize over
$sortKey = 'id';

// Key to concatenate
$concatenateKey = 'kid';

// Separator string
$separator = ', ';

foreach($rows as $row) {

    // Guard against invalid rows
    if (!isset($row[$sortKey]) || !isset($row[$concatenateKey])) {
        continue;
    }

    // Current identifier
    $identifier = $row[$sortKey];

    if (!isset($concatenated[$identifier])) {
        // If no matching row has been found yet, create a new item in the
        // concatenated output array
        $concatenated[$identifier] = $row;
    } else {
        // An array has already been set, append the concatenate value
        $concatenated[$identifier][$concatenateKey] .= $separator . $row[$concatenateKey];
    }
}

// Do something useful with the output
var_dump($concatenated);
```

Comment: Was exactly what I needed to do the job. I had to add more concatenate keys and conditions but it worked just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the data in a CSV file, I think that the easiest way to do what you want is build an associative array using the common data as key and modifing it if exists:

```
$array=[];
while ($a=fgetcsv($handle)){
   if (isset($array[$a[0]."-".$a[1]."-".$a[2]])) {
      $array[$a[0]."-".$a[1]."-".$a[2]].=",".$a[3];
   }
   else {
      $array[$a[0]."-".$a[1]."-".$a[2]]=$a[3];
   }
}
```